# IBOutlet is nil after flip transition animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

My two IBoutlet of two views are there which i am trying to flip. After UIView.transition, "from" IBOutlet sets to nil, unable to figure out the reason behind this.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var showingSideView: shadowView!
 @IBOutlet weak var hiddenSideView: shadowView!

 UIView.transition(from: showingSideView, to: hiddenSideView, duration: 0.7, options: transitionDirection) { (isFlipped) in

            self.showingBack = !self.showingBack
}
```

Comment: Can you write your IBOutlet definition code?

Comment: updated question, please have a look

Comment: Make it `strong` by removing `weak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read through the documentation :

> By default, the view in fromView is replaced in the view hierarchy by the view in toView. If both views are already part of your view hierarchy, you can include the **showHideTransitionViews** option in the options parameter to simply hide or show them.

So, to keep your views in the hierarchy, add that option:

```
@IBOutlet var showingSideView: shadowView!
@IBOutlet var hiddenSideView: shadowView!

UIView.transition(from: showingSideView, 
                    to: hiddenSideView, 
              duration: 0.7, 
               options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .showHideTransitionViews]) 
              { (isFlipped) in
                  self.showingBack = !self.showingBack
              }
```

**Edit:**

Just for clarification...

Apple now recommends NOT using `weak` for `@IBOutlets`, but that has no effect on the problem here. When using `.showHideTransitionViews` the reference will ***not*** become nil even if the `@IBOutlets` are set to weak.

Comment: .showHideTransitionViews this option fixed the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because your view in "from" will be removed from its superview after the transition finishes.

Read more in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622562-transitionfromview)

As you defined your outlet as weak, there is no retaining object anymore so it gets deallocated.

Comment: even i define my outlet as strong, issue is still there